# Downcasting doesn't work and functions called from object own class instead of where the function is (Java)

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, casting

i have this classes hierarchy:

```
public class Musician {
    private String name;
    public String instrument;
    public Musician(String name, String instrument) {
        this.name = name;
        this.instrument = instrument;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getInstrument() {
        return instrument;
    }
    private String getClassName() {
        return "Musician";
    }
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("[M] " + getName() + " plays music.");
    }
    public void printInfo() {
        play();
        System.out.println("[M] Class name: " + getClassName());
        System.out.println("[M] Instrument: " + getInstrument());
    }
}

public class RockMusician extends Musician {
    public String instrument;
    public RockMusician(String name, String instrument) {
        super(name, instrument);
        this.instrument = instrument + " and drums";
    }
    public String getClassName() {
        return "RockMusician";
    }
    @Override
    public void play() {
        super.play();
        System.out.println("[RM] " + getName() + " breaks his "
                + super.getInstrument() + "!");
    }
}

public class IsraeliRockMusician extends RockMusician {
    public IsraeliRockMusician(String name, String instrument) {
        super(name, instrument);
    }
    public String getInstrument() {
        return instrument;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName() + " the king";
    }
    public String getClassName() {
        return "IsraeliRockMusician";
    }
}
```

And i got this main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Musician("Gershwin", "piano").play();
    new RockMusician("Lennon", "guitar").play();
    ((Musician)(new RockMusician("McCartney", "bass"))).play();
    new Musician("Gershwin", "piano").printInfo();
    new RockMusician("Lennon", "guitar").printInfo();
    System.out.println(new RockMusician("Lennon", "guitar").instrument);
    System.out.println(((Musician)(new RockMusician("McCartney","bass"))).instrument);
    new IsraeliRockMusician("Chanoch", "guitar").printInfo();
}
```

I'm trying to understand few things:

First, how come the casting in the third line of my main function does nothing, it still calls the function from the `RockMusician` class even though i casted it to `Musician`.
Even in my compiler it says that this casting is "Redundant" and i don't understand why, as far as i know it should treat the object like it's from the `Musician` class and it doesn't.

Second, i would like to know how come that in the `printInfo()` method on the first line it calls the `play()` function, and it calls the `play()` function of the object class instead of stick with the `play()` function of the `Musician` class...
I'll explain myself, since the `getInfo()` class is found only in the super `Musician` class it will always go to that method, never mind what was the class of the object that called it.
So if I'll have a `RockMusician` object it will activate the `Musician` `getInfo()` method, but in the first line when it will try to call the `play()` method it knows that the object that called it was indeed a `RockMusician`, even if I'm calling it from a `Musician` method.

Hope i was clear enough, I'm not that new to OOP, but I'm new to Java, and i don't really understand how it works "under the hood"...

Hope you could help me, Thanks!

Comment: Please read up on [polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: Have you dealt with classical inheritance before?

Comment: @rgettman I'm familiar with polymorphism, i really tried to work it out with all the rules i know but still it remains pretty hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using inheritance within classes, overriding a method will ALWAYS call the child method regardless of casting. You can never change the type of an object, so a `RockMusician` - although it is an extension of `Musician` - is still a `RockMusician` and will be called by its type, not the superclasses'. This is so that one can use a `Musician` object to represent any type of `Musician`, but still use the child methods in each class.

To get around this, you could use a boolean flag within the play method, to call either the child or super method:

```
play(boolean callSuper) {
    if (callSuper){
        super.play();
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way all method call are resolved in Java.

First thes is no function, only method call on Object.  So the `play()` call in the `getInfo()` method is in fact calling the method play on the current object.  It is in fact the same as `this.play()`.

The method resolution in Java is done at run time base on the accual object the method is call.  The compiler will create byte code that will simply trigger the dynamic look up of the method to call.

This behavior enable polymorphism.

If you are comming from a C++ bacgroud, all method are virtual function.

This apply to non private method and non static one.

If `getInfo()` was calling a private method, there won't be any dynamic look up even if the sub class have a method with the same name that is not private.

For static method, you should always call it on the class directly not the object as it can be confusing as the compiler will then statcitly select the class on witch it will be called.